# Place of issue of passport

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, europe

I am a Hungarian citizen, and my sponsoring company is in the process of generating a work visa for me, specifically a certificate of sponsorship.

There is a section where they are required to enter the `"Place of issue"`. However, my passport does `not` have a designated field for this information. The only information I have on my passport is the `"Authority"`, which is `"Belugyminiszterium"` (Home Office in Hungarian), this is the official issuing authority. Is it acceptable to use this as the `"Place of issue"`? I would feel more at ease if there were fields for `"Issuing country: <Country>"` and `"Issuing authority: <Authority>"`.

Comment: I would put the name of the town or city where you applied for and received the passport.